# Manipulating Drupal 8 currentUser roles array

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I can retrieve the array of currentUser roles like this;

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser(); 
print_r($user->getRoles());
```

However, I want to remove a role from that array, and I am really struglling to do that, since that property is defined as `protected`. I have tried `$user->removeRole('role')` and `unset($user['roles']['role'])` but none of them works. is there really a way to invoke a role from the current user in drupal 8? If you know please instruct, considering me a dummy drupal developer. Thanks!

Comment: You can try `$user = user_load_by_name($username);`, and `$user->removeRole('roleToRemove'); $user->save();`

Comment: See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240062/user-removeroleadministrator-doesnt-remove-role and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_name/8.2.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxyInterface.php/interface/AccountProxyInterface/8.2.x

Comment: Thank you Brett this works, but I don't want this to be saved permanently in the database. I want this state to be kept true until the login session is alive.

Comment: basically my goal is to revoke the `superuser` role of a user if coming from outside a range of IPs. But logining back from within the range the user roles should loaded back and work normally.

Comment: Ah ok, that will be a little bit more tricky. When in your application lifecycle are you you currently doing the above? In a specific hook?

Comment: no I don't know how to write a hoke, but i am trying to add this functionality in the `src/LoginFirewall.php` file in `restrict_by_ip` module of drupal 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201037/discussion-between-saber-and-brett-gregson).

Comment: What behavior or action are you trying to control? My sense is that you will want to add a check at that point. For example inside hook_entity_insert, hook_node_access (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.2.x). To get the user IP: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/215783/70331

Comment: Thanks for getting back @Brian. Basically I am trying to use restrict by role feature of `restrict_by_ip` module (drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip), but this particular feature is not working. Even applied the patches that were provided, but the problem still exists, therefore I tried to implement this myself and I am struggling to remove the current user role in the session if loggining from outside the whitelist IP addresses. drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip/issues/2651106